# Where are netstat's -t and -u flags documented?

Tags: command-line, documentation, netstat

I use the following command to find open ports on my servers:

```
$ netstat -ntulp
```

I've probably found that on some random website over the years. However, I cannot find where `-t` or `-u` are documented. It certainly isn't in [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat). The man page does allude the their existence, and possibly hints that they are synonyms for `-tcp` and `-udp` (also undocumented, though easy enough to infer meaning for) respectively.

Though it *seems* that `-t` and `-u` are synonyms for `-tcp` and `-udp`, **where is this documented?**

Comment: What operating system? That command varies from system to system

Comment: Kubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manpage and `netstat --help` both say `[--tcp|-t] [--udp|-u]` in the synopsis. That's more than a hint - this syntax pretty clearly states that `-t` is the same as `--tcp` and that `-u` is the same as `--udp`. You're right though that the manpage doesn't document `--tcp` and `--udp`.

`netstat --help` shows that `--tcp` and `--udp` are two of the several socket selectors that you can use, see the `<Socket>` line:

```
host ~ # netstat --help
usage: netstat [-vWeenNcCF] [<Af>] -r         netstat {-V|--version|-h|--help}
       netstat [-vWnNcaeol] [<Socket> ...]
       netstat { [-vWeenNac] -i | [-cWnNe] -M | -s }

        -r, --route              display routing table
        -i, --interfaces         display interface table
        -g, --groups             display multicast group memberships
        -s, --statistics         display networking statistics (like SNMP)
        -M, --masquerade         display masqueraded connections

        -v, --verbose            be verbose
        -W, --wide               don't truncate IP addresses
        -n, --numeric            don't resolve names
        --numeric-hosts          don't resolve host names
        --numeric-ports          don't resolve port names
        --numeric-users          don't resolve user names
        -N, --symbolic           resolve hardware names
        -e, --extend             display other/more information
        -p, --programs           display PID/Program name for sockets
        -c, --continuous         continuous listing

        -l, --listening          display listening server sockets
        -a, --all, --listening   display all sockets (default: connected)
        -o, --timers             display timers
        -F, --fib                display Forwarding Information Base (default)
        -C, --cache              display routing cache instead of FIB

  <Socket>={-t|--tcp} {-u|--udp} {-w|--raw} {-x|--unix} --ax25 --ipx --netrom
  <AF>=Use '-6|-4' or '-A <af>' or '--<af>'; default: inet
  List of possible address families (which support routing):
    inet (DARPA Internet) inet6 (IPv6) ax25 (AMPR AX.25) 
    netrom (AMPR NET/ROM) ipx (Novell IPX) ddp (Appletalk DDP) 
    x25 (CCITT X.25)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure that the way the manual states it (`[--tcp|-t] [--udp|-u]`) does in fact meant that  `-t` is the same as `--tcp` and that `-u` is the same as `--udp`. Perhaps I should have quoted the manual as you have done and asked that specific question.

Answer (score 4):

The man pages are your friends for info such as this:

```
$ man netstat
...
SYNOPSIS
   netstat   [address_family_options]   [--tcp|-t]   [--udp|-u]  ...
```

Notice in the usage that those switches are the short forms of the GNU style switches `--tcp` and `--udp`.